# Ploting multidimensions survey responses using gglikert

Tags: r, ggstatsplot

Consider a data.frame from a resulting survey.

```
Question <- c("D1-Q1", "D1-Q2", "D1-Q3", "D1-Q4", "D1-Q5", "D1-Q6", "D2-Q1", "D2-Q2", "D2-Q3", "D2-Q4", "D2-Q5", "D2-Q6", "D3-Q1", "D3-Q2", "D3-Q3", "D3-Q4", "D3-Q5", "D3-Q6")
strong_agree <- c(23,NA,4,23,5, 7, 3, 12, 4, 7, 8, 11,5, 7, 22, 6, 3, 7)
agree <- c(23,42,4,23,5, 7, 23, 12, 4, 7, 8, 11,5, 7, 24, 6, 8, 7)
neutral <- c(3,34,4,23,5, 2, 3, 6, 4, NA, 8, 11,5, 7, 2, 3, 3, 7)
disagree <- c(21,12,4,23,5, 4, 2, 16, NA, 7, 8, 11,5, 7, 6, 6, 34, 7)
strong_disagree <- c(44,NA,4,23,5, 7, 2, 17, 4, 7, 8, 11,5, 7, 23, 6, 3, 7)
Dimension <- c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1",  "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3")
Region <- c("R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R3", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R3", "R1", "R1", "R2", "R2", "R3", "R3")

df <- data.frame(Question, strong_agree, agree,neutral, disagree , strong_disagree, Dimension, Region)

gglikert(df)
```

Using `gglikert`, from `ggstats` package how should the data be prepared in order to create a plot faceting or grouping (?) the Region and Dimension variables like in the image

[image: Survey results, by region]

I just can get around on how to use the `gglikert` to display the results, but it feel so easy.. I feel dumb.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think using `gglikert` is a bit over the top to create a simple stacked barchart which does not require more than reshaping your data to long and some vanilla `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Question, Dimension, Region), names_to = "label", values_to = "count") |> 
  ggplot(aes(count, Question, fill = label)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  facet_wrap(~Region) +
  theme_bw()
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (`position_stack()`).
```

[image]

And if you want to present your data as a likert chart you could easily do so by switching to `ggstats::position_likert` where I also have set NAs to zero and used `ggstats::label_percent_abs()` for the axis labels:

```
df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Question, Dimension, Region), names_to = "label", values_to = "count") |> 
  tidyr::replace_na(list(count = 0)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(count, Question, fill = label)) +
  geom_col(position = ggstats::position_likert()) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ggstats::label_percent_abs()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = "RdYlGn") +
  facet_wrap(~Region) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

And as a reference, here is the way to do it with `gglikert`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(Question, Dimension, Region), names_to = "label", values_to = "count") |> 
  replace_na(list(count = 0)) |> 
  uncount(count) |> 
  select(-Dimension) |> 
  mutate(id = row_number(), .by = Question) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Question, values_from = label) |> 
  gglikert(include = -c(Region, id), facet_cols = vars(Region))
#> Warning: Removed 108 rows containing missing values (`geom_text()`).
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but im trying to achieve the visuals of the figures created by the gglikert, pondering the negative and positive answers to either side and the neutral one in the middle. Also, the survey was prepared to use likert scale, so i thought it would be wise trust the math of a proper function/package created to deal with likert scale surveys.

Comment: The fact that you want to have a likert chart wasn't clear from your question which shows a stacked barchart. But you are right. I would use `ggstats` myself for likert charts. But `gglikert` is not necessary to do so. You simply have to switch the position. See my edit.